# Vim syntax highlighting randomly disappears while scrolling through *.vue component files

Tags: vue.js, vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using a plugin called `vim-vue` and whenever I scroll through my component file, the highlighting just turns off kind of randomly, and I have no clue how or why.

Where do I start with fixing an issue like this?

Comment: https://github.com/posva/vim-vue#my-syntax-highlighting-stops-working-randomly

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why they don't just include that "fix" in the plugin to begin with... oy!

Comment: @fabruex care to post an answer?